# What was the treatment of Polish POW in British or Soviet uniform in WW2?

Tags: world-war-two, poland

Suppose that Polish soldier, member of [Polish Armed Forces in the West](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_Armed_Forces_in_the_West), becomes a German POW. How good or bad would have be treated ? Like UK/US POW (relatively mildly) or like Polish POWs from 1939 (somewhat harsher) ? Is there a chance he would be considered an illegal combatant and executed ?

Same question about [Polish Armed Forces in the East](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_Armed_Forces_in_the_East). Would Germans treat them like captured Soviet soldiers (very poorly) or perhaps somewhat better ?

Sources that I have found ([this](https://www.histclo.com/essay/war/ww2/pow/ger/cou/pol/pgc-pol.html) for example) do not mention these two groups, they only mention original Polish POW from 1939, and captured members of [Armia Krajowa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_Army).